# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new to python and django. When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')'
mysql Server version: 8.0.13 MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I can't find this error on the web.

Comment: What version of openssl do you have on this server? What mysqlclient or MySQL Connector/Python do you have installed?

Comment: @danblack 'mysqlclient               1.3.13           py37h1de35cc_0'

Comment: @danblack My openssl's version:'OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:'https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html'

'shell> bin/mysql_ssl_rsa_setup'

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue too when installing from Anaconda, but I could work around it using the "use_pure=True" mysql.connector.connect() parameter.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same error when I tried to connect to MySQL to Python (in Anaconda).

[This feed](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10646) is particularly helpful for various case scenarios leading to the same error. For me, installing openSSL version 1.0.2r in Anaconda, itself, fixed the issue:

`$ conda install openssl=1.0.2r`

Comment: After 3 month i quit that issue. this finally solved it.
i owe you my life.

Answer (score 0):

Open The file **init**.py(file under the same directory as settings.py)
add the following code:

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()