# Python MySQLdb cannot connect to server, SSL Issue

Tags: python, openssl, conda, mysql-python

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')`

is thrown at me when I try to run my script which connects to my SQL server. 
I installed MySQLdb via conda. I've read that this may be an openssl issue, but I'm having trouble downgrading that as well.

Answer (score 0):

based on [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385113/django-db-utils-operationalerror-2026-ssl-connection-error-ssl-ctx-set-tmp).

> I got the answer:'https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html'
>
> 'shell> bin/mysql_ssl_rsa_setup'

If you want to deploy the server with automatic support for secure connections, use the mysql_ssl_rsa_setup utility to create default SSL and RSA files

[More information here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ssl-rsa-setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this my using `mysql.connector` instead of importing `MySQLdb` in my python scripts