# Keep having Error connecting Mysql to Python 3

Tags: python, mysql

I have Anaconda, MySQL workbench and mysql-connector-python-8.0.18-macos10.14.dmg installed.

Keep getting the error:

```
InterfaceError: 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed
```

I am using:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxxxxxx',
                              host='localhost')
try:
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   cursor.execute("""
      select 3 from your_table
   """)
   result = cursor.fetchall()
   print (result)
finally:
    cnx.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL\_CTX\_set\_tmp\_dh failed')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385113/django-db-utils-operationalerror-2026-ssl-connection-error-ssl-ctx-set-tmp)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: look this: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10646

Comment: just solved it using a solution from https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10646#issuecomment-515734257

Comment: mysql.connector.connect(host=..., user=..., passwd=..., use_pure=True)